# I am not able to trigger function inside page unload event?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
 $(window).unload(function () {
    window.readerControl.docViewer.trigger('AnalyticsForPublication', [Pageno]);
     // trigger the method
  });

 function AnalyticsForPublication(event, pageNumber) {
   alert('hello');
  }
```

Above trigger sentence is write for call AnalyticsForPublication function. trigger sentence
  is working all other scenario but not working inside unload event. Is there any restriction inside
unload event?

Comment: yes there are and this question has many many posts on this site. Please do some research

Comment: I tried all solution provided in other post but it is not work for this case. I thinks that unload event is triggered when browser is closed. and when browser is closed at that time all .js file is removed from browser and specific file method is not able to triggered.

Comment: not closed yet but it's too late to do anything important because user can leave fast